Isometry group of quadric model of anti-de Sitter space
I am learning Lorentzian geometry on my own. Consider the space $\mathbb R^{p+2}$ endowed with the bilinear form $$\langle x, y \rangle_{p,2} = \sum_{i = 1}^{p+2} x_iy_i -x_{p+1}y_{p+1}-x_{p+2}y_{p+2}$$ Then $(\mathbb R^{p+2}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{p,2})$ is denoted by $\mathbb R^{p,2}$.  We define the quadric model of anti-de Sitter space as $$\mathbb{H}^{p,1} = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^{p+2} \mid \langle x, x\rangle_{p,2} = -1\}$$   It is a Lorentzian manifold of dimension $p+1$  and  endowed with the Lorentzian metric $g\vert_{\mathbb{H}^{p,1}} : =  \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \vert_{T_x \mathbb{H}^{p,1}} $  where $T_x \mathbb{H}^{p,1} = x^{\perp_{p,2}}$ (orthogonal w.r.t $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_{p,2}$).
We define  $$O(p, 2) = \{A \in GL(p+2, \mathbb{R}) \mid \langle Ax, Ay \rangle_{p,2} = \langle x, y \rangle_{p,2} \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{p+2}\}$$
I want to prove  that  $\text{Isom}\ \mathbb{H}^{p,1} =O(p,2)$.
I have already proved that $O(p,2)$  acts   on  $\mathbb{H}^{p,1}$  and transitively. Then I have proved that for every linear isometry $L: T_x \mathbb{H}^{p,1} \rightarrow T_y \mathbb{H}^{p,1}$ there is an isometry $\phi: \mathbb{H}^{p,1} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}^{p,1}$ sending $x$ to $y$ such that $d\phi = L$.
But I cannot proceed further. Can you please help me?
